# Are Ignored Resources broken for EGit 2.1.0 and Eclipse 4.2.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I've been using Eclipse and EGit for months, and upon most recently running the Eclipse updater I've discovered EGit doesn't appear to be respecting the Ignored Resources preferences.

Does EGit store its configuration somewhere else? Is there a bug between these two versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since EGit 2.1, the "Ignored Resources" are no longer respected. You should explicitly ignore them using entries in your `.gitignore` file and commit the file.

The reason for this change is that the `.gitignore` file is also usable outside of Eclipse, e.g. when you use the command line or other people use different tools.

See [bug 359052](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359052) for more details.